# incompatible anonymous function signature in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create an extension method which I can invoke on an object .

The return value will be defined by a function.

Something like this :  ( *this is just an example* )

```
bool isMature= thePerson.Age.Apply<bool>(d =>   {    if (d >18) return true;
                                                        return false;
                                                 })
```

and here is the extension method :

```
  public static Tout Apply<Tout>(this Object obj, Func< Tout> f)  
        {

            return f( );
        }
```

The error : *incompatible anonymous function signature*

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: btw. `if(x) return true; else return false;` simplifies to `return x;` So your lambda can be written as `d => d > 18`

Comment: Do you want to extend `Object` or do you want a generic extension?

Comment: @CodesInChaos why did you delete your answer ?

Comment: Because I misunderstood the question. I thought you wanted to return a `Func<TOut>`, not a `TOut`. But returning a `TOut` it's unclear to me what this method is indented to achieve in the first place over just calling `f`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos f should be executed with the value from the extension method. I added an answer. ( and your solution does answer my question).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method takes just a `Func<Tout>` - which is a function *taking* no parameters, but *returning* a value.

Your lambda expression has a parameter (`d`) - and it looks like you're assuming that's an integer. It's not clear what you're trying to do, but if you want to use a parameter in the lambda expression, you're going to have to change the signature from `Func<TResult>` to `Func<TArg, TResult>` or something similar - and provide an argument in the invocation.

Comment: Jon I want to be able to retrieve a value of type `Tout`  via extension method which will be applied on any type which is `Tin`... ( instead of writing an outside function which will do this logic).

Comment: @RoyiNamir: You don't *have* a `TIn` - look at your code; it's nowhere to be seen. You could change your method to *have* two generic type parameters, but you need to do that... and then probably pass the value into the delegate. It's important that you understand what you've currently got though, and why it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

If looks like you're expecting the input to the delegate instance to be the property value, so you would need to change the definition of the extension method to take this argument:

```
public static TOut ToFunc<TProperty, TOut>(this TProperty obj, Func<TProperty, TOut> f)  
{
   return f(obj);
}

// Usage
bool isMature = thePerson.Age.ToFunc<int, bool>(d => d > 18);
```

It seems a strange approach whatever the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pointless excercise, [devdigital](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14734031/659190) has answered your question but what use is the answer.

So I can write the code,

```
var greaterThan18 = 20.ToFunc(n => n > 18);
```

but, why didn't I write

```
var greaterThan18 = 20 > 18;
```

all that is gained is a layer of indirection.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do something  like:

```
  public static Tout ToFunc<T,Tout>(this T obj, Func<T, Tout> f)  
        {
            return f(obj);
        }
```

And the invocation is

```
  var isMature = theperson.Age.ToFunc<int, bool>(i => i > 18);
```

However , I hated  specifying `<int, bool>` every time

But thanks to resharper - which *reminded* me - I can invoke it like :

```
  var isMature = theperson.Age.ToFunc(i => i > 18);
```

it is a nice util though , for small things. ( although it would be better to have a  bool property which will indicate `isMature`....but ....you know , its nice.)

Comment: Rename the method to `Apply`. You're not converting to a `Func`.

Comment: but, you could do `var isMature = theperson.age > 18` which is nicer. http://stackoverflow.comhttp://stackoverflow.com/a/14734687/659190

Comment: @CodesInChaos yeah. although its a short cut `To Function` and not `To Func`

Comment: please expand on that comment, are you talking about side effects?

Comment: There is no advantage to using this function, as Jodrell has stated.  It's not so much that it's bad, because it's *likely* not to cause problems, it's just adding extra code, extra complexity, and making the program slower for *zero* benefit.

Comment: @Servy I wanted to test something , and it didnt work. So I asked Waht I was missing. is that a crime ? can't people just test things ? ( the whole prob is pure generic help).

Comment: @RoyiNamir That's fine, so long as you recognize that the function itself is not useful and creating it is a purely academic exercise.

Comment: @Servy with a second look it helps in such way that it convert vertical code to hotizontal code.